# For every r exists large enough n such that any graph...

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

> Let $r$ be a natural number. Prove that there exists large enough $n$ , such that every connected graph on at least $n$ vertices contains $K_r$, $K_{1,r}$ or $P_{r}$ as induced subgraphs (first one is the complete graph , second is bipartite complete with one side of size 1 and the other side of size $r$ , and the last one is path containing $r$ edges

This smells like a question that requires the diagonal ramsey numbers , but I can't solve this.(I choose n=$R(r,r)+1$ but with no success )

P.S.: I am fully aware that there exists an answer for this question in Diestel's book , but I am looking for another proof(he uses a proposition we didn't learn in the course , but there is no way I would have thought about that proposition during an exam)

Comment: Which propositions are you allowed to use then?

Comment: Ramsey’s theorem. Upper and lower bounds for Ramsey numbers(for example erdos's thoerem regarding diagonal ramsey numbers).
And some generalization of ramsey numbers (where we color with more than two colors for example).
About other topics I can't really extend because we had multiple theorems, but I never have heard about radius of the graph (we did define diameter)

Comment: @bof yes , the graph is connected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a connected graph of order $n$ which does **not** contain $K_r,K_{1,r}$, or $P_r$ as an induced subgraph; I will derive an upper bound for $n$. Here $P_r$ is a path of **length** $r$, not a path with $r$ vertices. Let $R=R(r-1,r)$ be the Ramsey number such that any graph of order $R$ either contains an $(r-1)$-vertex clique or else contains an $r$-vertex independent set. Let $\Delta=\Delta(G)$ be the maximum degree of a vertex in $G$.

**Claim 1:** $\Delta\lt R$.

**Proof:** If there were a vertex $v$ of degree at least $R$, then by applying Ramsey's theorem to the subgraph  of $G$ induced by $N(v)$ we would get either $K_r$ or $K_{1,r}$ as an induced subgraph of $G$.

**Claim 2:** $\operatorname{diam}(G)\lt r$.

**Proof:** A shortest path from $u$ to $v$ is an induced path of length $d(u,v)$; since $G$ contains no induced path of length $r$, we must have $d(u,v)\lt r$ for all $u,v\in V(G)$.

**Claim 3:** 
$n\le1+\sum_{d=1}^{r-1}\Delta(\Delta-1)^{d-1}\le1+\sum_{d=1}^{r-1}(R-1)(R-2)^{d-1}.$

**Proof:** Choose a vertex $u$. It's easy to see that for $d\gt0$ we have 
$|\{v:d(u,v)=d\}|\le\Delta(\Delta-1)^{d-1}$; the upper limit of summation comes from Claim 2; and $\Delta\le R-1$ by Claim 1.

Hence, if $G$ is a connected graph whose order exceeds the bound in Claim 3, then $G$ must have $K_r$ or $K_{1,r}$ or $P_r$ as an induced subgraph.

Comment: "With the diameter bounded by r−1, a graph with a large number of vertices must contain a vertex of high degree. Finally, by Ramsey's theorem, if G contains a vertex of high degree, then G must contain either a large complete graph Kr or a large induced star K1,r." Can you explain both of those statements?

Comment: How did you get to the fact that your $n$ should be bigger than the expression you wrote?
Why high degree and bounded diameter gives complete graph/complete bipartite graph as induced subgraph?

Answer (score 0):

In claim 1, where seems to be a problem: if N(v) is a complete graph
then it's ok to say we have either an r-1 or r click but if N(v) isn't a complete graph
then you have a problem, where's really nothing to say in that case so how is it possible to use ramesy in that case?

Comment: if $|N(v)|\geq R(n,n-1)$ then by Ramsey numbers definition , N(v) contain a complete graph on $r$ vertices as a subgraph or has a independent set of size $r-1$ (becuase it's complement graph will have a complete graph on $r-1$ vertices), either way if $|N(v)|\geq R(n,n-1)$ then it easy